# Why would a framework implement factory methods to create simple primitive objects?

Tags: java, factory, factory-pattern

I'm working with a Java framework that uses factory methods to instantiate simple objects. For example they have their own Double object that you must instantiate using syntax like Double.make(). I'm not too familiar with factories but aren't they supposed to be used with more complex objects? Why have a factory method that's going to make me the same object every time? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Without seeing *any* code, we can but speculate. So, if I were to speculate, I would say you *are* missing something here.

Comment: maybe they were thinking about extensibility for some reason, and the factories are there in case permutations need to be introduced later

Comment: Strange things like this are often the result of porting libraries or frameworks from other languages. It could represent a "double" type from another language with a different specification than in Java. That would at least explain (but probably not justify) why they have their own double type.

Answer (score 1):

One reason I can think of to use factory method pattern in this scenario is to be able to control the object creation for class Double. I.e. it may return a new Double object everytime a call is made by invoking api `Double.make()` or it can choose to reuse an existing object and return that (even like a singleton pattern). Essentially this way you keep the control of object generation in the Double class and clients of that class don't need to know how the object is getting created that they are using.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense for `Double`, but it would make sense for `Integer`, `Short` etc. to reuse existing instances for common numbers like 0,1, etc...   Java provides `valueOf()` for that, so a factory is slight overkill, but still reasonable.

Comment: I think this might be it. The framework is for use in an embedded java system without much processing power.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a factory method regardless of the complexity of the object, as you are finding here. Without seeing any code or even knowing what framework you are using, or what project you are working on, I can't deduce why the original designer did what they did. But assuming you must use the framework, then getting used to it should be your best course I guess.